# Webform default validation message altering

Tags: 8, webforms

I am working with drupal8 site.Here i want to override the default "The email address %mail is not valid" email format validation message.I have checked with hook_form_alter to implement this.But no result.Is it possible to alter this message?

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 8, Webform uses Drupal's default Email Form Element. You'll have to override this element info and add your own validation message there.

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/8.5.x

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer creating a new webform handler which has custom validation for a specific field instead of using form alter.

I have created a gist for you place it to the correct folder (mymoduleName/src/Plugin/WebformHandler) clear cache and than attach the webform handler to your webform.

https://gist.github.com/benzo11/9e947c3732a5c90c749f8b8842c0baa3

Second is, that you create a new webform element which extends WebformEmailMultiple and overriding validateWebformEmailMultiple function(you can just copy paste it and change the text). But you will have to add a new webform element in webform.

I hope it can help you!